# Using swap! to update a vector of maps in a Clojure(Script) atom

Tags: data-structures, clojure, clojurescript

I have an atom holding a vector of maps (example code from c2 library):

```
(def ^:export data
  (atom [{:metric "Revenue", :units "USD in thousands"
           :ranges [150 225 300], :measurements [220 270], :markers [250]}
          {:metric "Profit", :units "%"
           :ranges [20 25 30], :measurements [21 23], :markers [26]}
          {:metric "Order Size", :units "USD average"
           :ranges [350 500 600], :measurements [100 320], :markers [550]}
          {:metric "New Customers", :units "count"
           :ranges [1400 2000 2500],
           :measurements [1000 1650], :markers [2100]}
          {:metric "Satisfaction", :units "out of 5"
           :ranges [3.5 4.25 5], :measurements [3.2 4.7], :markers [4.4]}]))
```

I can easily modify (well, create a modified copy) of this, incrementing the value of `:markers`, thus:

```
(map (fn [m] (update-in m [:markers] (fn [v]  (map inc v)))) @data)
```

I'm familiar with updating atoms with `swap!` in most cases, but the best I've been able to do in this case is the following:

```
(defn upmark []
  (let [new (map (fn [m] (update-in m [:markers] (fn [v]  (map inc v)))) @data)]
    (vec (reset! data new))))
```

Which is clearly bad since I'm resetting the entire state of the atom instead of just updating the pieces I need. I'm just confused why it's so difficult applying the code that does the required thing to an ordinary vector of maps with `swap!`. I get that `swap!` has an implicit `apply` but I can't seem to get the applied fn right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are really close. `(swap!)` applies the given function to the current value in the atom and any additional arguments passed into swap. So you can define a function that acts on a vector of maps and then use `(swap!)` to apply it to the value in the atom:

```
(def ^:export data (atom ...))

(defn upmark [data]
    (mapv (fn [m] (update-in m [:markers] (fn [v]  (mapv inc v)))) data))

(swap! data upmark)
```

Note that I changed a couple of instances `(map)` to `(mapv)` so vectors do not turn into lazy sequences.